# How to do a task immediately after installation of Android applucation..?

Tags: android

I'm developing an application in Android. Is there anyway that I can send SMS to destination number, saying my installation is successful - without opening the application or clicking any buttons - immediately after the installation.

Comment: That's a bit of an odd requirement. Just out of curiosity, why would you want that feature?

Comment: That's not possible... android phones make the user open the app explicitly... what you want could be dangerous if you think of it closer.

Comment: My Requirement is - user downloads my app from URL supplied by my server team & on click of it application gets installed in device. Then I've to update the server that the particular user's download and installation is successful by sending SMS to the server.

Comment: @Cristian: it doesn't make any sense to think of this as dangerous, as there are tons of things you can get events for that will happen "not terribly long after installation", like "screen unlocked" (or even "phone booted up", if you are willing to wait a little longer); it isn't like Android actually requires you to interact with the App before you can start doing things randomly in the background.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

The best you could do is set a flag in either the preferences or save it some other way, that does this on the first start of the application.